# Running a jar produce from gradle build

Tags: scala, gradle

I have a simple gradle file from which I build a jar file.
When I run the jar file however I get and error: 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Predef$'

The build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'distribution'

def mainClass = "com.domain.Hello"

distributions {
    custom {}
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.11.4'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClass
    }
}

task run(type: JavaExec, description: "Runs the project") {
    main = mainClass
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    classpath configurations.runtime
}
```

Comment: You're not adding the scala libraries in the classpath of the jar manifest, so that's not surprising. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the jar you need to include the scala-library on the classpath, like this

scala -cp [scala library jar] [project jar]

If you don't want to have to do this, take a look at this blog post http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/posts/2013/09/04/building-fat-jars-with-gradle/

Comment: Being scala, the run command is:
scala -cp [scala library jar] [project jar]

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/

Comment: mkyong example is buggy::you need apply `plugin:'base'` in the gradle.build file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include ''scala-compile' package beside 'scala-library'

Comment: Doesn't help - and also don't see this anywhere in documentation